# Read value from html file

Tags: asp.net, html, streamreader

I have a page that allowed user to insert some information and save as html file(not in DB). However, i need regenerate a report base on the information from all html file. 
For example, inside the html file consists of salary of the user, and i need to grab the value and sum the total of salary.

I plan to use StreamReader to read all the html file and store all salary into an array. But I am afraid that it might affect the performance of my application.
So, i wish to know that is there any better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

If your application allows the user to modify a html page content then surely it makes more sense to save the users input into an XML and then use that XML file for future manipulations and there-by leaving the actual HTML form untouched for the next(?) user.

Also your derived XML file can be as complex or as simple as you need.